# Error 1935.An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.4148"

Tags: windows, installation, windows-8.1

I have troubles installing *VC runtime libraries* to be able to install *SQL Server Compact Edition*.
The same problem causes also other apps to fail when installing, but I chose this one as a good representative example of my problem (and also it's provided by Microsoft, so "installation should work").

I took a look at what is usually provided as logs/more information and I put on Dropbox on this location: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zh7ajn50cxz7km/logs.zip 2 logs:

1. installation log with more info
2. procmon log of non-success and non-"result not found" while doing the installation step

Any idea what could be the cause and how to fix it?

**Edit:** CBS Log added: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vcru82wo12y5tj5/CBS.log

Comment: As you can see in the MSI logs, the underlying call to a function named `CreateAssemblyCacheItem` returns `HR=0x80070003` which is "Path not found". It's probably not msiexec.exe that encounters this fault, but some system component, rendering the ProcMon log kinda useless :-(

Comment: I need the folder **C:\Windows\logs\CBS** to see why this fails.

Comment: @magicandre1981: I've added the CBS log as well

Comment: I need the complete CBS folder with all files (copy it to the desktop and zip the folder)

Comment: @magicandre1981, here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4ygwvvw8kzk2q7e/CBS.ZIP

Comment: I can't see any error in the log :(

Comment: try the FixIt from this KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970652/en-us

Comment: @magicandre1981 that is one the things I tried. Automatic fix app doesn't work on Windows 8 BTW, but I have manually applied the fixes in the registry, restarted ... nope, same log output of the install

Comment: do the old Inplace upgrade (which also works for 8.1) to repair Windows: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html After this install the VC++ Runtime.

Comment: thanks @magicandre1981; I am not sure I am able to do it since I don't have retail Windows 8.1 installation (only the one given by laptop manufacturer, on a partition). I planned on resetting the entire laptop anyway since this problem doesn't plan on going away. Thanks anyway

Comment: you can find 8.1 retail ISOs in the Internet

Comment: where you able to find an ISO and repair Windows? Compare the SHA hashes from the MSDN subscriber page to make sure the ISO is untouched/unmodified.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was resolved by executing the Windows Refresh, which is destructive on many settings, but all other options were not working...

Answer (score 0):

All your msi can't be broken at same time, so it's windows installer fault.

big bang mode:

from a cmd elevated:

```
msiexec /unregserver
msiexec /regserver
```

Then install again

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help either (it was one of the things I tried)

Answer (score 0):

On a windows 2016 server, I solved the problem by relaxing a bit the DCOM security:
launch dcomcnfg
Then setting it to default:
[image]